# SDIO probe function isn't been called after moving SDIO device driver library to an old Linux platform using platform device and no device tree

Tags: linux-device-driver, platform, device-tree

I currently porting a sdio device driver (which's working on linux 4.3 or higher) to an old linux platform 3.10.14. The new one uses device tree to manage sdio bus and the driver uses some sdio api like sdio_register_driver, int sdio_probe(struct sdio_func*, struct sdio_device_id*), but the old one uses platform device with api platform_device_register used in the kernel. I installed the module to system have the old kernel and the probe function isn't called, please help me to fix this. I'm a newbie, I hope you guys can understand what I describe.

Thanks,

I tried replace field drv.of_match_table in struct sdio_driver (because of no device tree in old kernel) to drv.name (because platform device detects base on name field) but the probe function still isn't called

Comment: It's unclear what's the purpose to back port the driver to more than 10 years old kernel. Also your question needs more focus.

Comment: The hardware having the old kernel has worked perfectly for many years, so we don't want to replace the old kernel to the newer one. Instead, we back port the driver when we want to add a new component.

Comment: Ah, good luck then!